# VBA Access Format Chart in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2007, charts

**EDITED**

If you guys have a link that might help with this problem I'd really like to read it, because so far I haven't seen anything very useful.

In access I'm trying to export arbitrary data to excel, create multiple charts (right now just working on a pie chart), format these charts and then send them to a blank (Chart) sheet.  So far I've exported the data and am able to create the charts, I just have no idea how to format them.

The formatting I want to do is to get rid of the legend, put data labels with the name, value, and percentage, and move it to a "Chart" sheet.

**Edit I am now able to get rid of the legend as well as insert the data labels with name, value and percentage.  I am still stuck on moving the Chart object to a new sheet, code at bottom.**

I've also tried to record a macro in excel, edit it slightly and then move it over to access but I keep erroring out, usually with an error similar to "This object doesn't have that method".  Below I'll include a test table that I might get and how I create the pie chart.

Code:

```
Function Excel_Export_Two_Column()
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim WBO As Object, WSO As Object, WSO2 As Object, XLO As Object, oChart As Object
Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Integer, strTab As String, strcompany As String
Dim endTable As Long
Dim tempName As String, tempNum1 As Long, tempNum2 As Long, totalEnd As Long

z = 1
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("QRY2Col")

Set XLO = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
XLO.Application.Workbooks.Add

Set WBO = XLO.Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set WSO = WBO.Worksheets(1)
Set WSO2 = WBO.Worksheets(2)

WSO.Name = Left("export", 31)

For y = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    WSO.Cells(1, 1) = "Num"
    WSO.Cells(1, y + 2) = rs(y).Name
Next y

x = 1
Do While Not rs.EOF()
    x = x + 1
    WSO.Cells(x, 1) = x - 1
    For y = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        WSO.Cells(x, y + 2) = Trim(rs(y))
    Next y

    rs.MoveNext
    DoEvents
Loop

WSO.Cells.Rows(1).AutoFilter
WSO.Application.Cells.Select
WSO.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

x = 1
Do While WSO.Cells(x, 1) <> ""
    x = x + 1
Loop

endTable = x - 1

WSO2.Cells(1, 1) = "Name"
WSO2.Cells(1, 2) = "Num"
totalEnd = 2
For x = 2 To endTable
    If (WSO.Cells(x, 2) <> "") Then
        tempName = WSO.Cells(x, 2)
        tempNum1 = WSO.Cells(x, 3)

        For y = 2 To totalEnd
            If (WSO2.Cells(y, 1) = tempName) Then
                tempNum2 = WSO2.Cells(y, 2)
                WSO2.Cells(y, 2) = tempNum1 + tempNum2
                Exit For
            ElseIf (y = totalEnd) Then
                WSO2.Cells(y, 1) = tempName
                WSO2.Cells(y, 2) = tempNum1
                totalEnd = totalEnd + 1
            End If
        Next y
    End If
Next x

Set oChart = WSO2.ChartObjects.Add(500, 100, 500, 300).Chart
oChart.SetSourceData Source:=WSO2.Range("A1").Resize(totalEnd - 1, 2)
oChart.ChartType = 5

strcompany = "Export"
If Dir(CurrentProject.Path & "\COLA_AR_" & Format(Date, "yyyymm") & "_XXX_" & strcompany & ".xlsx") <> "" Then
    Kill CurrentProject.Path & "\COLA_AR_" & Format(Date, "yyyymm") & "_XXX_" & strcompany & ".xlsx"
End If

Call WBO.SaveAs(CurrentProject.Path & "\COLA_AR_" & Format(Date, "yyyymm") & "_test_2_Col.xlsx")


WBO.Close savechanges:=True
Set WBO = Nothing

XLO.Application.Quit
Set XLO = Nothing

rs.Close
db.Close
End Function
```

Table: Note that this table is in a Query (named "QRY2Col") in Access

```
Field1          Field2
CTOD            64646515
BFTBC2          6656532
WTOW            451512355
DT3             684321818
STC2            652553548
BFTBC2          12
DT3             84954987
ATCR            99999999
CTOD            64185435
BFTBC2          321569846
STC2            6543518
STC2            3518684
ATCR            35481354
```

**Code for data labels**

```
Set oChart = WSO2.ChartObjects.Add(500, 100, 500, 300).Chart
oChart.SetSourceData Source:=WSO2.Range("A1").Resize(totalEnd - 1, 2)
' Number corresponds to a pie chart
oChart.ChartType = 5

' Adds data Labels
oChart.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True

' Format chart
oChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.ShowCategoryName = True
oChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.ShowPercentage = True
oChart.SeriesCollection(1).HasLeaderLines = True
oChart.Legend.Delete
```

**Attempted code to move chart**

Below is an example of what I recorded (edited by adding "oChart") but this still doesn't work.  The problem that gets highlighted is the "xlLocationAsNewSheet" and VBA says that the "Variable is not defined".

```
oChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
```

Thank you,

Jesse Smothermon

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using late binding for all of this code? Using early binding, you'd at least get the intellisense as to what methods are available to you... i.e. `Dim WBO As Excel.Application` rather than `Dim WBO As Object` etc

Comment: Intellisense/Early Binding is for the developer. Late Binding is for the USERS, since it means your app is more robust when deployed. Most experienced Access developers switch back and forth between early and late binding, i.e., early for development, late for deployment.

Comment: @David Sadly I've had to do my fair share of VBA programming, and I completely agree with you... but it rather seems that Jesse is still in the development phase here and that early binding is far more appropriate at this stage...

Comment: Whenever I declared the variables as an Excel.Application or anything similar I get a "User-defined type not defined".  I tried Excel.Workbook and Excel.Worksheet but those didn't work either.  Object just happened to work ("work" meaning "compile")

Comment: Well, do you have a reference for the Excel object library? If you don't, then, no, you can't use the types defined in that type library. You might want to read Tony Toews's discussion of early vs. late binding: http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/latebinding.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the last part, try this:

```
oChart.Location Where:=1

' xlLocationAsNewSheet = 1
' xlLocationAsObject = 2
' xlLocationAutomatic = 3
```

As David pointed out, you cannot use the types/enums etcetera defined in the Excel object library without a reference to it, thus you are stuck using integer constants instead.

Comment: ...or you have to redefine them yourself. I always do it like this: `Someproperty = 1 ' xlLocationAsNewSheet` That is, I hardcode the value, but put in the named constant as a comment.

Comment: Since you're not referencing the object model, could you simply redefine the entire enum exactly? Or would that causing too many problems during development, when you __are__ referencing it?

Comment: Well, you can do that. I don't know exactly what happens when you have duplicate declarations, though, since you'd have one local to your Access project and one in the library you're referencing. I often switch to early binding during development (to take advantage of Intellisense), and so I tend to avoid the duplicate declaration problem, since I'm not sure what happens under those circumstances. Maybe it works fine -- but I've just avoided the issue because I don't want to take the risk.